# How can I create a global checkbox array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, checkbox, global

I'd like to create a global checkbox array that's accessible from anywhere.

```
static class global
    {
       public static CheckBox[] checks = { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox6, checkBox7 }; 

    }
```

This code underlines the checkboxes and sais:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication4.Form1.checkbox1'

Comment: checkbox1, checkbox2 instances should be static

Comment: Your CheckBox1 is instantiated?

Comment: also, this seems like a terrible idea

Comment: Your question is not well formulated . What are these Checkbox1 variables , CheckBox2 ... ?

Comment: @bergdavi, why you have to do this?

Comment: my money is on 'MVVM was too hard!' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dragged a checkbox on your winform, it is represented as 
    *WindowsFormsApplication4.Form1.checkbox1* which is an instance of checkbox. This can be checked if you go into definition of InitializeComponent() method of your form Form1. You will find *Checkbox checkbox1 = new CheckBox()*.

Since this object is defined in Form1 class and is not static so you can't use this in assignment to a static class.